# Html.DropDownListFor selecting item based on ModelState rather than Model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In asp.net mvc (v5 in my case), when you post a model back to a controller, and then render a view *with a model other than the one that was posted back*, then Html.DropDownListFor will select the selected item based on the data from the model that was posted back, rather than the model that was passed to the view.

Why is this?

Here's an example. When you select a new item in the first dropdown, the form posts back, and if the fist dropdown has id=2 selected, then the selectedId2 is changed and the second dropdown *should* render with the second item selected. However that's not the case. While the Model object in the view *does* have the new selectedId2 = 2 value, the DropDownListFor under the hood gets the selected value from the ViewState.ModelState object, not the ViewState.Model. What can be done to get the DropDownListFor to render based only on the Model passed to the view?

The Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var defaultModel = getModel();
        return View(defaultModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Model1 postedModel)
    {
        var defaultModel = getModel();

        if (postedModel.selectedId1 == 2)
        {
            defaultModel.selectedId1 = 2;
            defaultModel.selectedId2 = 2;
        }

        return View(defaultModel);
    }

    private Model1 getModel()
    {
        var items1 = new[]
        {
            new
            {
                Name = "Item 1-1",
                Id = "1"
            },
            new
            {
                Name = "Item 1-2",
                Id = "2"
            }
        };

        var items2 = new[]
        {
            new
            {
                Name = "Item 1-1",
                Id = "1"
            },
            new
            {
                Name = "Item 2-2",
                Id = "2"
            }
        };

        return new Model1
        {
            selectedId1 = 1,
            selectedId2 = 1,
            SelectList1 = new SelectList(items1, "Id", "Name", 1),
            SelectList2 = new SelectList(items2, "Id", "Name", 1)
        };
    }


}
```

The View Model:

```
public class Model1
{
    public SelectList SelectList1 { get; set; }
    public SelectList SelectList2 { get; set; }
    public int selectedId1 { get; set; }
    public int selectedId2 { get; set; }
}
```

The View:

```
@model Model1

@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedId1, Model.SelectList1, new { title = "Select 1", onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedId2, Model.SelectList2, new { title = "Select 2", onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
    </div>
}
```

Edit: **One Solution I found:** 
Adding this line before executing the View() clears out the posted model so that the DropDownListFor helper uses the model that is passed to the view:

```
ViewData.ModelState.Clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the selected value if you use the appropriate `SelectList` constructor:

[SelectList Constructor (IEnumerable, String, String, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

The last parameter is the selected item, which must be one object of the `IEnumerable`.

You are using this constructor, but are specifying `1` as the value. It should be something like `items1[0]`

Comment: Doesn't that just set the default item to be selected, which gets overridden by the selected item id provided in the model / lambda expression that is used in the DropDownListFor() call?

Comment: The MVC code for `DropDownListFor` is quite entangled. If you follow it you'll arrive to a point where you see a `SelectInternal` class that uses the `Selected` property of each item of the `SelectList` to decide if a value is selected or not (`SelectList` is an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. `SelectListItem` has a `Selected` property). Along the way it looks like there is not a single place where the `Selected` property is modified. I've been using it like this, and have never have troubles (at least in my usage pattern). Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: If you compare `DropDowListFor` to other helpers, there is a big difference: in the other helpers code you can see that they receive the model. The `DropDownListFor` doesn't receive it.

Comment: No, I think you're missing the main part of my question. It doesn't matter what you put as the selected item in either the view model, or in the constructor for SelectList, because the data in the model that is posted to the action gets used instead. If you look through the MVC code for DropDownListFor, you'll see that the selected value gets pulled from ViewState.ModelState, and not ViewState.Model. My issue exists when the view renders on POST - no issue when the view renders for a GET. I did find that adding ViewData.ModelState.Clear(); before I call View() in my controller action works.

Comment: Have you tried my solution and it fails? If so, please, let me know, and I'll try to repeat it with a proof of concept. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I tried your suggestion, and it does nothing different. The item gets selected based on the model that is posted.